# Move center of the 360 deg. panorama image

Tags: c#, image, panoramas

I have a 360 degree image and want to move it in C# by x degrees horizontally.

Here is an example:

[image]

and here is result I want to get:

[image]

Not sure where to start - should it be 'sliced' into 360 pcs and redrawn or is there other C# approach to move an image in such a way.

Comment: Your question is way too broad - unless you have extensive knowledge of image manipulation (in which case you'd probably have a decent idea where to start), this touches on several advanced topics that cannot be covered in a simple answer.

Comment: "Not sure where to start" == not ready to post a question.

Comment: Anyway, a hint: you only need to slice it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about simply panning the image and not sphere-mapping it or anything fancy, you only need to cut it into two pieces.

[image: screenshot]

Just make a new bitmap of the same size, then use [`Graphics.DrawImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142038.aspx) to draw the two sections in reverse order.